# How to add Range Input to VBA UserForm

Tags: vba, excel

Many of the built in excel dialog boxes use a range input box like this one:

[image: Range input Boxes in Excel]

Im not sure if they are called "Range Inputs" or whatever. This is taken from "Data Analysis" in Excel, in case you are wondering. When you click on the little image in the text box, the dialog box disappears  and excel allows you to select a range of cells, which it then places in the the text box. If there is a way to incorporate this into a UserForm, please let me know

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [RefEdit Control](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213776) and works similar to that built in Boxes.
If your toolbox does not have a RefEdit control, set a reference to RefEdit control. Click Tools, References, and check Ref Edit Control.

Here is an Example how to use it: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/userform-ranges.html

Comment: Thank you for letting me know/the example, exactly what I needed!